# Car engine dies when I am not pressing the Gas

Tags: engine, chevrolet, stall, aveo

Make: Chevrolet Aveo UVA 1.2 LT 2007 model.

When ever the gas is not pressed, the engine stalls. Even the engine does not start unless I press the gas while turning the key.

At high speeds everything seems OK.

It does makes a strange rumpling sound at higher RPMs.

I got the electrical fuse checked and they seems OK, as initially the mechanic thought it was an electrical issue to stop.

Recently I drove it to my home town for 150km and there was some burning oil smell. Now it is even taking longer time and throttle press to start. I checked the oil levels and they seem OK.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a very dirty throttle body.  If the engine is very worn, there could be a lot of gasses/oil vapours being blown into the air intake which could cause a build-up of gunk around the throttle butterfly and idle control valve.  This could block the required air for idle, which would then cause the engine to stall.  Try taking the intake pipe off the throttle body and clean the internals.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced such with my Honda City 2005... I had to change the whole engine cos some of the valves were no more in position as the mechanic said.

Tell your mechanic to take a good look at the engine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the fault, I don't understand what you are saying the problem was?

Comment: It stalls after some minutes and will have to let it cool before starting the engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro but... Same symptoms observed for a Lambda Sond problem.

In fact it could be a "sond" problem, the lambda one calculate the good "gas/air", it's a frequent case of an unwanted turn-off. It could be also for example the temperature sond, which cut when the temperature is to high (when you stop the wind can't refresh your engine) it can also be a problem with the piece which set the "idle power" of your engine.

Comment: Can you expound as to what exactly you are talking about and why you think this is the issue? Maybe more about how they might get the problem fixed? We don't need pros, just *good answers* ... Please just flesh it out a little :D

Comment: In fact it could be a "sond" problem, the lambda one calculate the good "gas/air", it's a frequent case of an unwanted turn-off

It could be also for example the temperature sond, which cut when the temperature is to high (when you stop the wind can't refresh your engine)

it can also be a problem with the piece which set the "idle power" of your engine

Sorry for my english, I'm not native...

Comment: Threw that in as an edit ... you should be able to edit your own posts here. You aren't a newbie to SE ;-)

Comment: By "sond", you mean sensor?

Answer (score -1):

Could be a worn out timing belt. If you have clocked more than 100,000 then it is advisable to replace timing belt, idle and have the engine retuned or rather check the timing. Better to check the timing belt before buying a new one as the problem could be elsewhere dirty nozzles, fuel pump, etc it could be anything